# Long press home button in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, button, home-button

I think in my application according to intercept the long home button, for their own operations, I want to know this, can pass through the apple's audit? If not approved, that where can I find on the home button that use the terms?

Comment: Why do you even want this? It's a really bad idea to modify how the user interacts with the device.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112723/ios-home-button-warning-is-it-possible):

> Apps that alter the behavior of switches on the device will be rejected

This alters the behavior of the home button switch, so it'll be rejected. If you can even write it, that is.