# How to trigger iOS home button long press

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, hid, siri

I want to trigger iPhone's home button long press event to open Siri from my application. How it is possible? Is there any way to do so using programming or Bluetooth HID protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Siri from your code is not possible if you want to submit your app to the AppStore, but if you're not looking to do that, have a look at this:

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649602/can-siri-be-invoked-programmatically-within-my-app-using-private-apis)

About the HID protocol:

I don't think so, but I would not rely on this information.

Answer (score 0):

From the App Store guidelines (slightly abbreviated):

> Apps that alter the behavior of switches on the device will be
>   rejected

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7112754/1537036) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. Apple haven't provided access to those API.

Hope we will have it after WWDC 2015 :)