# Allow User Input Before App Enters Background

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a CoreData app with a fairly long list of data fields. When a user edits the fields but attempts to exit the DetailViewController without saving the edits, I put up an alert asking if they really want to discard the changes. This works fine, but if the user taps the home key, the edits are lost. I've tried to present an alert before the app enters the background but have been unable to delay entry into background to allow for user input. Is it possible to delay app entry into the background while waiting for user input?

Here's what I tried:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ notification : Notification) {
    //this does not work - alert is too late
    cancelUnsavedEdits()
    //try above
}//applicationWillResignActive
```

The canelUnsavedEdits method is fairly straight forward:

```
func cancelUnsavedEdits() {

    if hasChanged {

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Edits", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            self.codeDismissTheKeyboard()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMasterViewController", sender: self)

            let editRecordButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.edit, target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.editThisRecord))
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editRecordButton

            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

            //need to remove the edits - refresh the original page
            self.configureView()

        }))//addAction block

        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save Edits", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            self.codeDismissTheKeyboard()
            self.saveTheEditedRecord()
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMasterViewController", sender: self)

        }))//addAction block

        //for -ipad add code in handler to reopen the fields for editing if the cancel of the cancel is chosed
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (whatever) in
            //print("makeEntryFieldsEnabledYES for ipad")
            self.makeEntryFieldsEnabledYES()
        }))
        //above for ipad

        self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        self.codeDismissTheKeyboard()

        //add this for ipad
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        //add above for ipad

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMasterViewController", sender: self)
    }//if hasChanged

    //this for ipad
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    //above for iPad

}//cancelUnsavedEdits
```

Any guidance on a strategy to accomplish this idea would be appreciated. iOS 10, Xcode 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS home button warning, is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112723/ios-home-button-warning-is-it-possible)

Comment: Could you change where you reset the edit fields? While it makes much sense to put up a "Are you sure?" when leaving the detail view screen, it also make much sense to return the user to the exact same point - detail view screen with the fields as they were - after pressing the home button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not possible.

iOS does give your app some time to clean up or save data, but not enough time for user interaction. The reasoning is that the user DID interact and wants to exit your app. Maybe save the data the user entered and present it when they return, but do not try to prevent the user from exiting.